# Mongoose - find() not returning anything when no parameters are passed, but returns data when parameters are passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have the following model in `teamMembers.js`:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const teamMembersSchema = new Schema({
    uid: String,
    name: String,
    hours: Number
})

const TeamMembers = model('teamMembers', TeamMembersSchema);

module.exports = TeamMembers;
```

I've created the following endpoints in `teamMemberRoute.js`:

```
const TeamMembers = require('./models/teamMembers');

module.exports = (app) => {

    app.get('/api/pods/teamMembers/:uid', async (req, res) => {
        let teamMember = await TeamMembers.find( {'uid': req.params.uid } );
        return res.status(200).send(teamMember);
    });

    app.get('/api/pods/teamMembers', async (req, res) => {
        let teamMembers = await TeamMembers.find();
        return res.status(200).send(teamMembers);       
    });
}
```

The first endpoint (`/api/pods/teamMembers/:uid`) works just fine - when I pass a `uid` it returns documents specific to that `uid` in the TeamMember collection.

The second endpoint should return all documents from the TeamMember collection since no parameters are passed. However, when the request is executed, only `[]` is returned. We know for a fact that documents exist in the TeamMember collection, since the first endpoint returns data from that collection based on the `uid` parameter that is passed.

I'm stumped on this. Any ideas? I don't think there is anything wrong with my model since I am able to execute the first endpoint with no issues.

Comment: `.find({})` doesn't work either. I know that `.find()` works because I've used it against another Collection that returns all the documents. But for some reason it doesn't work on this TeamMember collection.

Comment: Yes I tried it. It doesn't work.

Comment: What's `app`? In the normal case, Express doesn't do anything with the return value of a route callback, so if the promise from your async function is being rejected, it wouldn't do anything with that reject (though Node.js would typically show it). But if you're using Koa or something... Are you sure you aren't getting a rejected promise?

Comment: `app` is a variable for Express. It's initialized in my `server.js` as `const app = express();`. I don't think I am getting a rejected promise.. I don't see anything being returned. I also tried adding a `console.log('test')` on the first line of the second async function, but nothing even gets printed out when the request is executed.

Comment: Whether it's the issue or not, those handlers are incorrect. You need to handle rejection of any promise in the handler, Express won't do it for you. (This is basically a matter of wrapping the handler code in a `try`/`catch` and sending an error response from the `catch` block. Best to wrap that up in a utility function.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express executes code from top to button, and that is the reason for this issue. It will match your first endpoint and assume that `uid` is `null`. Just change the order of defined endpoints, like this:

```js
module.exports = (app) => {

    app.get('/api/pods/teamMembers', async (req, res) => {
        let teamMembers = await TeamMembers.find();
        return res.status(200).send(teamMembers);       
    });

    app.get('/api/pods/teamMembers/:uid', async (req, res) => {
        let teamMember = await TeamMembers.find( {'uid': req.params.uid } );
        return res.status(200).send(teamMember);
    });

}
```

Comment: `null` or `undefined`? (Actual question.)

Comment: Now that you say it, maybe it will also be `undefined`, but in both cases it will not be equal to any `uid` for Mongoose to match it. @T.J.Crowder